# golang template.ParseGlob not reading files in root directory

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have a golang code as follows

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    // Parse all templates that match the recursive glob pattern
    templates := template.Must(template.ParseGlob(filepath.Join("templates", "**", "*.gohtml")))

    // Execute the base template to render the combined content
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "base.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

and the templates are in the following structure

```
templates
├── base.gohtml
└── nested
    └── index.gohtml
```

when I run this program, it's showing this error

```
panic: html/template: "base.gohtml" is undefined

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
```

when I move the base.gohtml into nested directory, it works as expected. is there any problem with the pattern ?

Comment: according to [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#ParseGlob), it says "The returned template will have the (base) name and (parsed) contents of the first file matched by the pattern". So [the algorithm](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match) is probably matching `index.gohtml` first. You could test this theory with `ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.gohtml", nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program `filepath.Join("templates", "**", "*.gohtml")` gives you a file path that should match `templates/**/*.gohtml` and since we have `/**/` in there it should match any directory but not root, and then inside that directory any gohtml file which is why files in the template dir are not getting matched but everything inside nested is. And if you have any other dir, the gohtml files inside it would also get matched.

So yeah there is a problem with the pattern and more details can be found in [go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match)

Also more can be found out on [Issue#11862](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11862) on go's repo!